# как получить код html-страницы средствами Python?

Tags: python

с  помощью какой функции , модуля.

Answer (score 3):

Например так

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen("http://ya.ru")
print f.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#examples

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к другим ответам есть еще внешняя библиотека [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). У нее по мнению многих, в чье число и я вхожу, более красивый интерфейс чем у стандартных библиотек.

Answer (score 0):

Python3

```
import urllib.request

f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://ya.ru").read()
print(f)
```

ИЛИ

```
import urllib
import requests

f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://ya.ru").read()
print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Простой страницы, динамически не меняющейся

```
import urllib
import requests

url='https://ya.ru'
r = requests.get(url) #url - ссылка
print ('reached 1')
print(r.headers['content-type'])  # 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
#before test what is it
if (r.headers['content-type'].lower()=='text/html; charset=utf-8'):  #it may be different
    print ('reached 2')
    html = r.text
    print(html)
```